# How i can set date picker range with in a financial year based on the document date? Im using JQUERY to do this

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, razor

I want to set my date picker range with in a financial year based on the document date.I get the document date , but i want to work this when the document is in edit mode and only for the particular Date section only.

```
 <div class="col-md-6 no-padding">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EnquiryDateFormatted, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label lblrequired" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EnquiryDateFormatted, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control newinput datepicker", @autocomplete = "off",@id="enquiryDateID" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EnquiryDateFormatted, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

this is the HTML section for selecting the date

```
 try {
        debugger;          
        $('input.datepicker').datepicker({
            format: "dd-M-yyyy",
            maxViewMode: 0,
            todayBtn: "linked",
            clearBtn: true,
            autoclose: true,
            todayHighlight: true             
        });

    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
```

this is the date picker script.

Comment: which datepicker are you using?

Comment: its bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: I created a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ewGZqg) to reproduce your issue, did this fiddle satisfy your requirements? I used `startDate` and `endDate` for determining date range.

Comment: thank you @TetsuyaYamamoto. let me check

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto here i cannot hard code startDate and endDate it will vary based on the document date

Comment: The `d` and `y` option for `startDate` and `endDate` automatically adjusts the dates according to date displayed in textbox, try changing passed date from controller and see if the range changes because I don't see why that's not working in your case.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto in my case financial year must be based on the document date .for example if document date is 05-Dec-2018 then date picker must range from 1-Apr-2018 to 31-Mar-2019.  This will vary based on the document date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the the methods [setStartDate](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html?highlight=clearDates#setstartdate) and [setEndDate](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html?highlight=clearDates#setenddate) for this.

The code will be something like this

```
$('#yourDatePickerID').datepicker('setStartDate', '04/01/2018');
$('#yourDatePickerID').datepicker('setEndDate', '03/30/2019');
```

or

you could use data attributes `data-date-start-date` and `data-date-end-date`

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" data-date-end-date=“mm/dd/yyyy”>
```

**Use this to get financial year**

```
function getCurrentFinancialYear(strDocDate) {
  var startYear = "";
  var endYear = "";
  var docDate = new Date(strDocDate);
  if ((docDate.getMonth() + 1) <= 3) {
    startYear = docDate.getFullYear() - 1;
    endYear = docDate.getFullYear();
  } else {
    startYear = docDate.getFullYear();
    endYear = docDate.getFullYear() + 1;
  }
  return {startDate : "01-Apr-" + startYear, endDate: "31-Mar-" + endYear };
}

alert(getCurrentFinancialYear("4/1/2018").startDate);
```

So your code should be like

```
$('#yourDatePickerID').datepicker('setStartDate', getCurrentFinancialYear(enquiryDateID).startDate );
$('#yourDatePickerID').datepicker('setEndDate', getCurrentFinancialYear(enquiryDateID).endDate);
```

Comment: thank you @kiranvj. But here my financial year must change based on the document date

Comment: eg: based on todays date. financial year will be from Apr1 2018 to 31 march 2019

Comment: Do you have the document date in a Javascript variable? Or is it available in C# end?

Comment: yes i have document date using an id enquiryDateID on the javascript side

Comment: thank you very much let me try with this code. i will update result here

Comment: what you mean by `getCurrentFinancialYear(enquiryDateID)` enquiryDateID in the function parameter

Comment: enquiryDateID  is the js variable name which you have the document id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184742/discussion-between-dhanil-dinesan-and-kiranvj).

Comment: `return {startDate : "01-Apr-" + startYear, endDate: "31-Mar-" + endYear };` here **startYear** and **endYear** are numbers and which is append with "01-Apr-" is there any problem with that

Comment: @dhanildinesan Not be a prob. Javascript takes care of that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `startDate` and `endDate` setting to enforce start and end dates, but you need to create a function to get fiscal year range first:

```
function getCurrentFiscalYear(date) {
    var dates = {};

    var docDate = new Date(date);
    var month = docDate.getMonth();

    if (month > 3) {
         dates.sDate = new Date(docDate.getFullYear(), 3, 1);
         dates.eDate = new Date(dates.sDate.getFullYear() + 1, dates.sDate.getMonth() - 1, 31);
    }
    else {
         dates.sDate = new Date(docDate.getFullYear() - 1, 3, 1);
         dates.eDate = new Date(docDate.getFullYear(), dates.sDate.getMonth() - 1, 31);
    }

    return dates;
}
```

Then, assign the function above to datepicker instance through [`startDate`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#startdate) and [`endDate`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#enddate) properties (they also accept JS `Date` instance besides of date string):

```
$('input.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: "dd-M-yyyy",
    startDate: getCurrentFiscalYear($('input.datepicker').val()).sDate, // start date
    endDate: getCurrentFiscalYear($('input.datepicker').val()).eDate, // end date
    maxViewMode: 0,
    todayBtn: "linked",
    clearBtn: true,
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true          
});
```

**Note:**

If you have multiple datepickers to handle calendar selection, change the selector in both `startDate` and `endDate` based from nearest element (e.g. using `closest()`, `siblings()`, `find()`, etc.)

The example implementation can be seen in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ewGZqg).

**Side note:**

The `EditorFor` containing `htmlAttributes` parameter only works for MVC 5.1 and above. If your MVC version is 5.0 or below, use `TextBoxFor` helper instead:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EnquiryDateFormatted, "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control newinput datepicker", @autocomplete = "off", @id="enquiryDateID" })
```

Comment: @Testsuya Yamamoto thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 0):

here is the correct answer to my question
@kiranvj give me the key to the answer with a small change

here i am posting his part code and my part code

code from @kiranvj

```
 function getCurrentFinancialYear(strDocDate) {
  var startYear = "";
  var endYear = "";
  var docDate = new Date(strDocDate);
  if ((docDate.getMonth() + 1) <= 3) {
    startYear = docDate.getFullYear() - 1;
    endYear = docDate.getFullYear();
  } else {
    startYear = docDate.getFullYear();
    endYear = docDate.getFullYear() + 1;
  }
  return {startDate : "01-Apr-" + startYear, endDate: "31-Mar-" + endYear };
}
```

and my part code

```
 $('input.datepicker').datepicker({
            format: "dd-M-yyyy",
            maxViewMode: 0,
            todayBtn: "linked",
            clearBtn: true,
            autoclose: true,
            todayHighlight: true,
            startDate: getCurrentFinancialYear(enqDate).startDate,
            endDate: getCurrentFinancialYear(enqDate).endDate
        });
```

Comment: This is more generic way to do it. This applies to all datepickers in the page while my answer above targets a single datepicker which can be used when different dcouments are involved in a page.

Comment: @kiranvj thank you very much for your valuable information. Yes your correct but we can use date picker id to apply to specific date pickers only.

Comment: `$('#ServiceCallDateFormatted').datepicker({
                format: "dd-M-yyyy",
                maxViewMode: 0,
                todayBtn: "linked",
                clearBtn: true,
                autoclose: true,
                todayHighlight: true,
                startDate: getCurrentFinancialYear(serviceCallDate).startDate,
                endDate: getCurrentFinancialYear(serviceCallDate).endDate
            }); `                                                                                                                                   this is one example

Answer (score 0):

```
function getCurrentFinancialYear(strDocDate) {
    var startYear = "";
    var endYear = "";
    var docDate = new Date(strDocDate);
    if ((docDate.getMonth() + 1) <= 3) {
        startYear = docDate.getFullYear() - 1;
        endYear = docDate.getFullYear();
    } else {
        startYear = docDate.getFullYear();
        endYear = docDate.getFullYear() + 1;
    }
    console.log({startDate : startYear+"-03-01", endDate: endYear+"-03-31" });
    return {startDate : startYear+"-03-01", endDate:  endYear+"-03-31" };
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.datepicker').datepicker({
      format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
      maxViewMode: 0,
      todayBtn: "linked",
      clearBtn: true,
      autoclose: true,
      todayHighlight: true,
      startDate: getCurrentFinancialYear($('input.datepicker').val()).startDate,
      endDate: getCurrentFinancialYear($('input.datepicker').val()).endDate
  });
});
```

[Checkout this](https://gist.github.com/dev-jaskaranSingh/ca951a44e60b9f300ca013cfe61fca77)